# How do i get thin fonts when using google fonts? I used font weight:thin; but it doesn't do anything

Tags: html, css, fonts

Example

```css
p { font-weight: thin}
```

```html
<p>This sentence is thin</p>
```

Comment: It depends on the font you are using but generally thin is `font-weight: 100` but thin can be anywhere in betweeen 100 - 300, 400 being regular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<
Font weight list

1. 100 — Thin / Extra Thin / Hairline
2. 200 — Extra Light / Ultra Light
3. 300 — Light
4. 400 — Regular (Normal)
5. 500 — Medium
6. 600 — Semi Bold / Demi Bold
7. 700 — Bold
8. 800 — Extra Bold / Ultra Bold
9. 900 — Black / Ultra Black / Heavy

> Blockquote

!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

```css
p { font-weight:100;font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;}
```

```html
<p>This sentence is thin</p>
```